# How to submit html form from one server (coldfusion) to another (node)?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, post

I am trying to submit a simple form using POST in a coldfusion website. The destination is nodejs server. I get 404 error. UI shows "Cannot POST /" and debugger console shows 404. Debugger console shows the data posted via the form (hidden text field). I read online it has something to do with CORS. How do I fix the problem? rather implement it correctly? Do I need to send headers with the request? If so, how do I do that? Please help!

This is my coldfusion code. It is a simple form posting:

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="nodeserver/#/myapp/new">; 
<input name="data" type="hidden" id="hiddenField" value="<cfoutput>#form.data#</cfoutput>" /> 
</form> 
<script> document.form1.submit(); </script>
```

Destination page is on another server and for now, it's just a simple hello world angular code (on nodejs server):

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("HelloController", function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "Hello, AngularJS"; 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Update: It seems the issue is on the destination server (in angular code) because if I change method in source site/form from POST to GET, then user does not get "Cannot POST /" error and the actual page shows on the destination site but now the problem is that URL shows posted data as querystring and then redirects the user to the login page. After user logs in, the querystring and subsequently the data is lost. I guess I have to add code in angular to manage the POST request. Does someone know how to do that?

Comment: So are you using the full URL? Show your code....

Comment: "I read online it has something to do with CORS." — That seems unlikely. You are submitting a form, not using Ajax. You've said nothing about any error message that would suggest CORS was the solution.

Comment: *UI shows "Cannot POST /"* — That just means your node.js code is reponding with a 404 Not Found to the POST request. Do you have some reason to think it shouldn't? You failed to include a [mcve] so we can't tell what the node.js code is supposed to do.

Comment: yes I am using full url. will send code in a min! It's on the other server. Could it be authentication? because source and destination servers, both require user to be logged in. I don't think that can be the issue because the data posted from source server shows in debugger console on destination site. It is definitely headers and I don't know how to pass headers in the form. Thanks for your help!

Comment: "Could it be authentication?" — It says "404 Not Found". If it is authentication related then the Node.js server is lying.

Comment: "Destination page is on another server and for now, it's just a simple hello world angular code (on nodejs server):" — Angular runs **on the client**, not in Node. (You might use Node to compile the Angular app to ES5). You have not shown the code which receives the POST request and returns a 404 error.

Comment: "It is definitely headers " — You seem very sure of that. What headers are you talking about? Why would missing headers result in your server saying that `/` was Not Found?

Comment: @Quentin, thanks for taking the time to read my post and helping. If I had an answer or if I were that technical, I wouldn't have asked the question here. I am basically a designer and my manager who assigned this task to me thinks it is a very simple task. I am sure with your help I can implement it correctly. Sorry if my question seems very dumb!